# Showing a quotient group $G/\langle x_0\rangle$ to be a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abelian-groups

There is an infinite p-primary group which is not isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_{p^∞}$ :

$G=\langle x_0,x_1,\ldots\mid px_0, x_0-p^nx_n\rangle$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Can I ask any hints, for showing that $G/\langle x_0\rangle$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups?

Comment: simply rewrite the presentation of $G$ by replacing $x_0$ with $0$ - you should see it then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you describe $G/\langle x_0\rangle$ in a similar fashion as your defined $G$? Or if you want : Knowing that in $G$ you have $p x_0 = 0$, $p^n x_n = x_0$ and that $x_0 = 0$ in $G/\langle x_0\rangle$, you should get simpler relations.

Comment: I am really thinking of showing that this quotient group is finite, so the problem will be easy by applying "Basis Theorem" next.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. You can get a very explicit decomposition if you write the presentation of $G/<x_0>$.

Comment: For future reference $<,>$ are interpreted as relations, you want \langle and \rangle instead.